# splitting file into multiple files within a while loop

Tags: awk, while-loop

I have a file like this (InFile.txt):

```
TOM1 LE1 1 
TOM1 LE2 1 
TOM1 LE1 2 
TOM3 LE2 2 
TOM1 LE3 3
```

The output would be three new files labeled **1.txt**, **2.txt**, and **3.txt**, which are generated from the original file based on having the value in column 3 in common.

**1.txt**

```
TOM1 LE1 1 
TOM1 LE2 1
```

**2.txt**

```
TOM1 LE1 2 
TOM3 LE2 2
```

**3.txt**

```
TOM1 LE3 3
```

I have been trying to do this as follows but struggling with my syntax

```
awk '{ i = 1; {while (i < 100); if($3 == i) print $1 " " $2 " " $3; InFile.txt > $i.txt} i++}' InFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk '{ filename=$3 ".txt"; print $0 >> filename}' yourfile
```

**Explanation:**

- `$3 ".txt"` - Forming filename using `$3` value.
- `print $0 >> filename` - Appending the current line(`$0`) to corresponding
  filename.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. a lot more straight forward to how I was approaching it.